# How to calculate fees,total and subtracting it from the initial balance in a separate App

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

VIEWS

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
    def send(request):
        posts =Transactions.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        form =  TransactionForm()
        if request.method=="POST":
            form = TransactionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.instance.user=request.user
                # x=(form.cleaned_data['recipient_sending_amount'])
                form.save()

            return redirect('/success/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Failed, Resend')
    context = {'form':form, 'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'index_user/send-money.html', context)
```

MODELS

```
class Transactions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,related_name='users',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipient_account_type = models.CharField(max_length=230)
    recipient_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    recipient_acount_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    recipient_routing_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    recipient_bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    recipient_swift_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    recipient_sending_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    transaction_ID =models.CharField(default=ID,max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    transaction_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=transfer_status, default='COMPLETED')
    fees =models.IntegerField(default=32,blank=True)
    total =models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    status =models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=status, default='COMPLETED',blank=True)
    colour =models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=colour, default='Blue',blank=True)
```

FORMS

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields = ['recipient_account_type','recipient_name','recipient_acount_number','recipient_routing_number','recipient_bank_name',
        'recipient_swift_code','recipient_sending_amount','description','fees',]
```

CustomUser in accounts app

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices, max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField()
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    account_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, default=account_number)
    account_status = models.CharField(choices=account_status, max_length=100, default='Active')
    account_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    routing_number = models.CharField(default=Routing_number, unique=True,blank=False, max_length=20)
    account_type = models.CharField(choices=account_type_choices, max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='directory', default='default.jpg', blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    montly_income= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    montly_withdraw = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I'm new to python and i don't seem to know how to calculate with fields that are blank and were not added to the form but have default value like the fees and total in models.
I HAVE ANOTHER FIELD IN ACCOUNT APP IN MY CustomUser MODEL NAMED  account_balance WHICH I WANT TO SUBSTRACT THE TOTAL FROM. Please can someone help me out

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Can you please also provide the CustomUser model?
Do you want to add Total Transactions Fees of a Client (user) and then subtract it from his/her balance? Also, where do you need the result? In a view? In a function? In a field of a model?
As a general direction, (if you need the Total Transactions Fees of a Client (user) and then subtract it from his/her balance) you should:
- select all Transactions of the user you are

Comment: After saving i want to do the calculation through instance values but i don't have any idea about how to go about it ****recipient_sending_amount + fees then save the result in total and then also substrate the result from  account-balance which is in Custom user model in accounts app****

Comment: I have added my CustomUser Model, i want to substrate the calculation from the (account_balance)